# Ruby on Rails 4.1. How add current password to the edit form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

In the section 9.1 of the book ruby on rails tutorial "Updating users" , I would like add  a field "current password" at the Edit form before to save the changes? 
What is the better way?

Thank you

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't add current password in the form, becuase

1. You shouldn't really know the password in the first place, it's encrypted right? cause it should.
2. If we ignore point (1), putting a plain password in the form can easily be inspected by any web inspector ( webdev tools, firebug, etc ), or even you can access it by simple js

You should instead handle it like @Stanislav mentioned, but I would add an extra check to see what the user is actually trying to change, like for example:

- If the user is only changing his display name or notifications settings for example, then you might not want to ask for the password in that case.
- if the user is trying to change his email, or credit card info, or address for example, maybe you'd want to verify the identity of the user.

Here's a simple fast example of how i might try to implement this (probably could be optimized in several ways)

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :password, presence: {message: 'you need to enter your password'}, if: :password_required?

  private
  def password_required?
    changes.keys.any? { |key| ['credit_card', 'address', 'email'].include? key }
  end
end
```

You could add another method to verify the correctness of the password, if not then just add an error message to the object's 'errors' attribute and that would fail the validation and prevent the object from being saved

```
before_save :check_password, if: :password_required?
def check_password
  self.errors.add(:password, 'Password is not correct') if password_is_not_correct?
end
```

I have to mention at the end that implementing your own authentication methods/libraries isn't safe, because there's a lot of ways to exploit that, instead you should use gems that are tested and have matured over the time, one of them for example is the `devise` gem

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing custom authentication, then you can add accessor to your user model and validate it

```
class User < AR::Base
  attr_accessor :current_password

  before_save :check_current_password

  private

  def check_current_password
    # custom validation logic here
  end
end
```

Comment: OP want add a field "current password" at the Edit form.

Comment: So, he can simply add it to form. Attr_accessible creates virtual field, that is not persisted in DB. But he can deal with it like with simple model field.

Comment: Stanislav Mekhonoshin i know it =).

Comment: So, what's the problem? Topic starter wants to add this field to form. I've provided a way how to implement this field at model, and after that he can simple add it to form, like any other field.

Comment: OP question it is off-topic and should be closed, because primary opinion based and have many possible answers. Your answer it is too broad. Make it better and i upvote.

Comment: OP didn't provide enough info in question. That's why my answer is too broad, so I can't give exact code that solves the problem. 
And BTW, you disvoted my answer, but not the question.

Comment: i do not down vote question, i cast to close it. if it is so important to you, i upvote. after 30 min.